# Integrating a google map into rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

Has anyone got any suggestions on where to start with building a google map into a rails app? I would like users to be able to add a marker by clicking the map, and have spent a few days looking for a suitable tutorial or plugin (beyond ym4r), to little avail...any help would be much appreciated as I am finding the Google Maps API rather difficult to get into! I've also come across the railskit for google maps - does anyone have any experience in using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably wouldn't use YM4R. We tried it and found that it doesn't add much value because it just wraps the API. I would recommend working with Google Maps directly from JavaScript. Google Maps API documentation is pretty good, and there are quite a few [examples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/) on the web.

There is an example of a click handler on the map [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/event-simple.html), and adding a marker is just a matter of doing

```
map.addOverlay(new GMarker(latlng));
```

Comment: Cheers! Any reason to favour GMaps V2 over V3?

Comment: @Sonia: You should use version 3 actually, I've just checked and it's become the official version. When I was using the API a few months ago, V3 was incomplete, so I just grabbed a V2 link.

Comment: v2 is oficially deprecated now. Few minutes v2 broke along. It still work with minor fix, but its the best sign to move away to v3.

Answer (score 3):

Just fyi, I made https://rubygems.org/gems/gmaps4rails which is a useful wrapper with several options.